# can't get irexec to work on RPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, infrared, lirc

I am trying to use an IR receiver LED driven by GPIO on the Raspberry Pi. 
I set up the lircd, taught it about the remote with irrecord, irw shows the keys I'm pressing:

```
# irw
0000000000f94ab5 00 KEY_1 /root/lircd.conf
0000000000f94ab5 01 KEY_1 /root/lircd.conf
0000000000f94ab5 02 KEY_1 /root/lircd.conf
0000000000f94ab5 03 KEY_1 /root/lircd.conf
0000000000f94ab5 04 KEY_1 /root/lircd.conf
```

yet irexec doesn't do anything.

My ~/.lircrc looks like this:

```
begin
 prog=irexec
 button=1
 config=echo "Yay"
end
```

I start irexec like this:

```
# irexec ~/.lircrc
```

and then it seems like it's waiting for input but nothing comes.

How can I check if irexec is getting the keypresses? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
begin
 prog=irexec
 button=KEY_1
 config=echo "Yay"
end
```

Try this lircrc, the button has to be named the same way irw says!